# IE 9 Compatibility for Javascripts: ChildNode, SetAttribute

Tags: ie-developer-tools

Many of the Javascripts functions are not working in IE 9.

To be specific, we have constructed some HTML contents dynamically. Now, when we tried to acess the content of an HTML table by using childNode element, the object is not completely retrieved into it.

But, when we run the same in IE 9-compatibility mode we were able to get it.

Code sample:

```
       var _object = document.getElementById(strTableId).childNodes[0]
       for (var iCount = 0; iCount < _object.childNodes.length; iCount++) {
            if (_object.childNodes[iCount]) {
                _object.childNodes[iCount].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                _object.childNodes[iCount].style.color = 'black'
            }
        }
```

Now, when we debug the code, we could see the objects existing in the variables, but the style properties and others are not accessible. Hence, the backgroundcolor line throws a javascript exeption.

Kindly help!

Answer (score -1):

IE 9 not support ChildNodes[0]. We can use children[0] instead of ChildNodes[0]

Mohan.K